# How to pass country code when using jquery autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using jquery auto complete to show country name when user type any character.
when user click button then i like to know how could i send country code to server side action instead of country name.

this is just a sample of jquery autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="plugins" name="plugins" />

var myData =[
    {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
    {"name": "Aland Islands", "code": "AL"},
    {"name": "Bahamas", "code": "BM"},
    {"name": "Bahrain", "code": "BH"},
    {"name": "Cambodia", "code": "CM"},
    {"name": "Cameroon", "code": "CN"},
    {"name": "Zambia", "code": "ZA"},
    {"name": "Zimbabwe", "code": "ZB"}
];

$(function() {
  $("#plugins").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = [];
      $.each(myData, function(k, v) {
        // Make a pass for names
        if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(req.term.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
          results.push(v.name)
          return;
        }
      });
      resp(results);
    },
        select: function( event , ui ) {
            alert( "You selected: " + ui.item.label+' values '+ ui.item.value );
            return false
        }    
  });
});
```

i know country code is not there in json. i will write there later country code in json. just tell me the way to send country code to action.

now issue is fixed. working version of jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/urtkxo46/8/

Comment: jquery autocomplete can take an object with label value keys. just set the name as label and country code as value

Comment: how to capture the selected value? better share a relevant link if possible.

Comment: check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/urtkxo46/ where data arrange as label and value wise. now tell me when user select any data from dropdown then how could i store selected data's value which later i can pass to server side function.

Comment: ui.item.value  not giving me the selected value. where i made the mistake?

Comment: you are not having any label value object. you are still only adding values. `results.push({"label": v.name, "value": v.code})`

Comment: yes you are right. i update the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/urtkxo46/8/ thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
$( function() {
    var projects = [
        {
            value: "1",
            label: "jQuery"
        },
        {
            value: "2",
            label: "jQuery UI"
        },
        {
            value: "3",
            label: "Sizzle JS"
        }
    ];
 
    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
        }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<div>" + item.label + "</div>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="project-label">Select a project (type "j" for a start):</div>

<input id="project">

<input type="text" id="project-id">  <!-- change it to hidden and get its value -->
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vmu7282/21/)

Comment: tell me what this line is doing `    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<div>" + item.name + "</div>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };`

Answer (score 0):

jquery autocomplete can take an object with label value keys. just set the name as label and country code as value

```js
var myData =[
    {"name": "Uganda", "code": "UG"},
    {"name": "Kenya", "code": "KY"},
    {"name": "Tanzania", "code": "TZ"},
  
];

$(function() {
  $("#plugins").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = [];
      $.each(myData, function(k, v) {
        // Make a pass for names
        if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(req.term.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
          results.push({"label": v.name, "value": v.code})
          return;
        }
      });
      resp(results);
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      alert(ui.item.label) //when selected the label shows in alert
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<input type="text" class="form-control" id="plugins" name="plugins" />
```

Comment: how to show value in alert when user type and select anything ?

Comment: think you want to use autocompletes `select` event [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)